Fiber keeps breaking inside the connector when terminating
I'm still a beginner when it comes to Fiber optic termination, I'm an IT Manager and I was asked to run a fiber cable from the our office to a new warehouse(Approximately 350m). I'm already at the termination stage and testing but for some reason, the fiber optic keeps breaking inside the connector. I'm already experienced with terminating since I've successfully terminated on of our ISP's because we have to move Offices but this current problem I'm facing is frustrating me. I don't know if it's the fiber optic or the connector(I'm using a Blue SC Connector btw). Does anyone have a suggestion on what I have to do?

What tool is being used to terminate the SC connector?

I'm using Miller clamps, Fiber coating stripping pliers and FC-6S cleaver. That's all.

Is it broken on making the connection, or does it break later (e.g., due to vibration or tension)?
